# Three.js: How to merge two BufferGeometries and keep transforms?

Tags: three.js

A non-buffergeometry, [`Geometry.merge()`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/core/Geometry), takes a matrix to apply to the geometry when merging:

```
.merge ( geometry, matrix, materialIndexOffset )
```

However, [`BufferGeometry.merge()`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/core/BufferGeometry.merge) does not take a matrix:

```
.merge ( bufferGeometry, offset )
```

I have confirmed that merging two BufferGeomtries together does not preserve transforms of the objects being merged.

Here's the kicker: I would like to do this **without converting to a Geometry at any step.** I would like to do it all in BufferGeometry land.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

We have been doing sich merging of (mostly single objects) to maintain the transformations for JSON Object exporting.

To bake the transformations we do run a small function

```
getFixedMesh = function(geometry) {
    var fixedmesh = null;
    switch (geometry.constructor.name) {
        case 'BufferGeometry':
            var srcmesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry);
            srcmesh.updateMatrix();
            return THREE.BufferGeometryUtils.mergeBufferGeometries([srcmesh.geometry]);
        default:
            var srcmesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry);
            srcmesh.updateMatrix();
            fixedmesh = new THREE.Geometry();
            fixedmesh.merge(srcmesh.geometry, srcmesh.matrix);
            return fixedmesh;
    }
}
```

This works for many arrangements, but still does some errors on LineSegments (and others?)

Answer (score 0):

BufferGeometry has .applyMatrix ( matrix ) method that you can use to 'bake' object transform into vertex data before merging it.

Comment: This is probably the only answer, but bufferGeometry.applyMatrix() doesn't appear to be doing what I want. I clone a geometry into a buffergeometry, apply the matrixWorld of the geometry, and merge it into another buffergeometry. when I add the big merged object to my scene, it's all compacted together. the transforms don't appear to be added correctly